# Zsh: timeout for vared builtin

Tags: shell-script, zsh, prompt, control-flow

I've got a while loop that uses [`vared`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-vared) to prompt for user input. I am looking for a way to have it timeout, execute a default variable and loop back to the prompt if there is not user input after a certain amount of time. I am aware of the read command and its timeout argument, but is this somehow possible with `vared`?

Also, is there a way to set a default for `vared` that doesn't print to the prompt?

```
local command

while :

   do
     echo "Enter a command or type 'quit' to exit:"
     vared -p "[*]: " command

     if [ "$command" = "quit" ]; then
         break

     else
         run command
     fi

     clear

   done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
default=foobar
if
  command=$(
    saved_settings=$(stty -g)
    trap 'stty $saved_settings; exit 1' ALRM
    v=
    TMOUT=10 vared -p "Enter a command [$default]: " v &&
      printf %s $v
  )
then
  command=${command:-$default}
  printf 'Got: "%s"\n' $command
else
  print timeout
fi
```

Instead of *priming* the variable with the default value, we prime it with the empty string and only set it to the default value if the variable is still empty after `vared` returns.

To handle the timeout, we use the `$TMOUT` special variable in a subshell which causes `zle` to exit that subshell after `$TMOUT` seconds.

That's a 10 seconds global timeout. Another approach could be use the terminal line discipline inter-character timeout, (`stty time x`, with `x` expressed in deciseconds), to give the user enough time to enter a large command but timing out after say 3 seconds of inactivity:

```
default=foobar
if
  command=$(
    saved_settings=$(stty -g)
    trap 'stty $saved_settings' EXIT INT TERM ALRM
    zle-line-init() stty -icanon time 30 min 0 <&2
    zle -N zle-line-init
    v=
    vared -p "Enter a command [$default]: " v &&
      printf %s $v
  )
then
  command=${command:-$default}
  printf 'Got: "%s"\n' $command
else
  print
  print timeout
fi
```

Note that while those work in scripts, [it currently doesn't work in interactive shells](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2020/msg00225.html) as `vared` there will refuse to run in subshells. If you need to run that from within and interactive shell, until that's fixed in `zsh`, you can change the:

```
command=$(
  ...
)
```

To

```
command=$(default=$default zsh -c '
  ...
')
```

Comment: I've tried to implement your suggestion, but I get the following error when trying to run vared using command substitution: "vared:12: ZLE not enabled."  Must I somehow enable the zle in the subshell? Thanks!

Comment: @Le_Prometheen strange. It works for me. You could try adding a `zmodload zsh/zle`. At least with 5.7.1, zsh/zle is loaded automatically upon the first invocation of `vared` whether it's in a subshell or not.

Comment: @Le_Prometheen, oh I see what's going on, you're trying it in an interactive shell and it seems indeed that you can't use vared in a subshell in that case. That doesn't sound right. I'll enquire about it on the zsh-workers mailing list. That code should work in a script though.

Comment: I am running a script, but it requires user input. I've gone back to trying to work with the read builtin, but it has its issues. Vared worked so well for user input, but I cant get it to timeout. I'll continue to try to experiment with your suggestions too.

Comment: @Le_Prometheen, that code should work at getting user input from a script as long as that script is not sourced from an interactive shell (and the script doesn't start with `#! /bin/zsh -i`). How are you running the script? See also yesterday's edit for a work around when sourced from an interactive shell.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Could you get `vared` to work in command substitution under an interactive shell? If not, what can I use instead?